# Align TextView to the bottom of an ImageView inside a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/miclubpyme_backgroundl" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStoreName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="I am a text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to have the TextView to align to the bottom of the ImageView, but not outside it. Adding the layout_alignParentBottom makes the RelativeView to occupy the full height of the screen.

Here is an image exemplyfing this:

[image]``

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Which part is the image and which part is not?  Looks like there is another portion that takes up the space between the image and the bottom of the device layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to nest your ImageView and your TextView inside a ViewGroup which has the same height as your ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/miclubpyme_backgroundl" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStoreName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="I am a text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `android:align_bottom="@+id/img"` on your TextView, not `android:align_parentBottom="true"`.

Comment: No, I've tried that and it didn't work for me.
Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try below in your textview  `android:layout_alignBottom`="@id/img"`

Comment: No, I've tried that and it didn't work for me.
Thanks though.